# Stripe multi vendor payment gateway using stripe API's in Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, connect

I have created API's in laravel where user can buy and sell its products on a platform (android & iOS) app .
User is paying when he is buying any product .
Payment amount is going to Admin (Stripe dashboard) .
so what i need to do after that is ---- i am calculating stripe fee and application amount then i want to pay the rest amount to seller .

i have created an API where buyer will mark "mark completed" after he will recieved a product or seller will mark "mark completed" after he will successfully sell the current product in its chat hostory also buyer and seller both can mark dispute in this api

so how can i create a charge to pay the rest amount to seller after completion of a product's selling or buying that is marked by a user or seller .

please let me know if there is something best

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) for paying your vendors. You can make separate charges once the item is bought and transfer the calculated amount to the seller once it is marked completed. Click [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers) for more details about this.